# Insert into a colum the month/day/currentyear that is the same month/day as a previous column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

My first question. I've searched, and have come close. But alas, here's what I am trying to do.

I have thee columns in the same table, Date1, Date2, Date3.

I would like to take the date from Date1 and insert the same month and year into Date2 with the current year. For example, if Date1 is 02/01/**2007**, I would like to insert 02/01/**2014**  into Date2. Then insert into Date3 a date 60 days from Date2.

**Current**

```
Date1             Date2           Date3
02/01/2007        NULL            NULL  
08/15/2009        NULL            NULL  
12/15/2011        NULL            NULL
```

**Expecting**

```
Date1             Date2           Date3
02/01/2007        02/01/2014      04/01/2014 
08/15/2009        08/15/2014      10/15/2014
12/15/2011        12/15/2014      02/15/2014
```

I think that's really it. I hope I didn't leave any thing out. FWIW, I'm working off of the UPDATE concept, but I can't figure it out.

Anyway, thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What platform? I think the answer is somewhat implementation-specific.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The question states MS SQL 2008R2 with a 2005 db.

Comment: @jpw: Now it does :) (-- or perhaps I missed it the first time around).

Comment: Nah...I edited the post. Sorry about that 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dateadd` and `getdate` functions to generate the dates you want. Try something like this to test it:

```
declare @d1 date
set @d1 = '02/01/2007'

select 
    @d1 as d1, 
    dateadd(YEAR, year(getdate())-year(@d1), @d1) as d2, 
    dateadd(day, 59, dateadd(YEAR, year(getdate())-year(@d1), @d1)) as d3
```

This would return:

```
d1         d2         d3
---------- ---------- ----------
2007-02-01 2014-02-01 2014-04-01
```

You might have to fine-tune the parameters to dateadd to get exactly what you want.

To adapt it to an update statement you would do something like:

```
update myTable
    set date 2 = dateadd(YEAR, year(getdate())-year(date1), date1) , 
    date3 = dateadd(day, 59, dateadd(YEAR, year(getdate())-year(date1), date1))
```

Comment: Well, I've tried this many times and when I use my update statement I continue to get
'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Comment: But I am marking it as correct FWIW. It answered the question and helped me move on from there. Thank JPW.

Comment: @NWHikerOR Happy to have been of some help :)